# Publishing a HTML page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, publishing-page

I have a HTML page and i need it to be published in SharePoint 2010. But i really don't know how to publish it and didn't even find any guide for it.

And for [enabling publishing features in share point i tried this , but it populates some error as below.](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Enable-publishing-features-in-SharePoint-2010-18ee3cfe-7ac1-4b47-93f0-98b5468c50a1)

> Publishing sites and features cannot be activated in the Central Administration Web Application. WebUrl: 'mySiteUrl'

Can anyone please tell me what are the steps for publishing a page in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn some basics of SharePoint to start with, like creating Web Application, site collection and so on. You tried to activate Publishing feature on the administration web application, which is not used for your work; it's meant for the administration of the different sites.

To start with create a separate web application and than site collection - choose Publishing Template for the site collection you create. Than navigate to the site collection and create a separate page (or edit home page) and drop a Content Editor Web Part (learn how to use Web Parts).. Go to Web Part properties and find how to link an HTML file with Content Editor Web Part..